# What are the effects of non-ultraviolet light radiation on DNA?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, light

I am trying better understand the effects of varying the frequency of light on DNA, however, most of what comes up is "UV light" and how it is damaging to DNA (presumably by ionization). Have there been any studies on radiation on DNA at lower frequencies of light?

Comment: have you tried googling?

Comment: yes that's why i'm here. everything i get keeps going back to uv light on dna.

Comment: Visible light aids DNA reparation after UV exposure (in prokaryotes at least) by activating the machinery. High-energy radiation (x-ray, gamma) causes double-strand DNA breakage (i.e. tears DNA into pieces).

Comment: @EliKorvigo any reference?

Comment: @aaaaaa Sure, [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/16699813/) is for the visible light part, [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC328056/) is for the double-strand breaks

Comment: @EliKorvigo I think this is a good answer to OP if you format it as such

Comment: @EliKorvigo I'm unable to look at the full article, but I want to know what spectrum of light they used, and what sort of dependence on the frequency is observed in terms of the repairs that take place. Is this the only study that has been done or is there a broader field of study that this topic heads under?